# What makes my code run so slowly?

Tags: vba, excel

As I said in the title, I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out why my code is running so slowly (Ran for an hour with no result). I'm very new when it comes to writing in VBA, but I don't see a reason why it would take so long. Here is the code in question:

```
Sub fast()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim prices As Worksheet
Dim stockreturns As Worksheet
Dim index As Worksheet
Dim stockprices As Range

Set index = Worksheets("IndexPrices")
Set prices = Worksheets("HistPrices")
Set stockreturns = Worksheets("Sheet1")

index.Range("A:B").Copy stockreturns.Range("A:B")

For col = 1 To 975
    For n = 2 To 260
        prices.Range("A:A").Offset(0, col).Copy stockreturns.Range("A:A").Offset(0, 2 * col + 1)
        If stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value = Null Or IsEmpty(stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value) Then
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1) = Null
        Else
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).Formula = Cells(n, 2 * col) / Cells(n + 1, 2 * col) - 1
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End If
     Next n
Next col

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'd be happy to post the workbook if anyone wants to see what I'm trying to accomplish in the sheet and potentially suggest a different or more efficient way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: For a start, move the statement `prices.Range("A:A").Offset(0, col).Copy stockreturns.Range("A:A").Offset(0, 2 * col + 1)` to before the loop on `n`. This will boost tour code by a lot. You were uselessly copying the same column to the same place 260 times.

Comment: Why are you coping the cells?   Do you need copy the cells formats? Or just their values?

Comment: @A.S.H I think the same, not only slow down the code but also might reset the answer.

Comment: I did move that copy out of the n loop, haven;t tested the code on the full 975 col values yet. Copying the cells just to get the dates and values, as I'm using them to calculate returns on the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code did what you want, the below redrafting should be much quicker.

1. Avoid using `.Copy` wherever possible. Instead directly assign the `.Value` of cells.
2. Make sure your lines of code are within the correct loops to avoid running code more often than it has to be run.
3. Stop doing every operation on entire columns, that's **a lot** of cells you're copying, of which 99% will be blank! I've taken the most basic approach possible and chosen to just use the first 1000 rows, improve this as suits - possibly by [finding the actual last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba).
4. Disable the automatic `Calculation` as well as the `ScreenUpdating`.

See code comments for details.

```
Sub fast()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Stop Excel from recalculating the workbook every time a cell value changes
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim prices As Worksheet, stockreturns As Worksheet, index As Worksheet
    ' Fully qualify your sheets by specifying the workbook
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set index = .Sheets("IndexPrices")
        Set prices = .Sheets("HistPrices")
        Set stockreturns = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    End With
    ' Assign some last row number so you don't have to be copying the value of tens of thousands of rows 
    ' Previously every values copy was on the entire column, wasting a lot of time!
    ' Could get this value by a cleverer, more dynamic method, but that depends on needs.   
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 1000
    ' Assign values, don't use copy/paste. Avoiding the clipboard speeds things up
    stockreturns.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value = index.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
    For col = 1 To 975
        ' This line isn't affected by the value of n, so move it outside the n loop! Again, use .Value not copy
        stockreturns.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Offset(0, 2 * col + 1).Value = prices.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Offset(0, col).Value
        For n = 2 To 260            
            If stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value = Null Or IsEmpty(stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value) Then
                stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1) = Null
            Else
                stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).Formula = Cells(n, 2 * col) / Cells(n + 1, 2 * col) - 1
                stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End If
         Next n
    Next col
    ' Reset Application settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wolfie, thanks for this. You're right about the speed-up. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Before we move on the optimization, let's make sure at least it works. Please check where I comment.
Assume that code above is correct. And in your code, you just modify to 260 rows so that I set last row to 260. I think this will need deeper debug to work. but if you follow this way, it will end up your program finish much faster (like hundreds of time faster than all normal methods above)
The concept is similar.
1. Dump all data to memory ( array "stockdata and "pricedata")
2. Play with data in memory
3. write back to file
4. add format if required.

```
Sub fast()
Dim stockdata,pricedata As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Stop Excel from recalculating the workbook every time a cell value changes
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim prices As Worksheet, stockreturns As Worksheet, index As Worksheet
    ' Fully qualify your sheets by specifying the workbook
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set index = .Sheets("IndexPrices")
        Set prices = .Sheets("HistPrices")
        Set stockreturns = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    End With
    ' Assign some last row number so you don't have to be copying the value of tens of thousands of rows
    ' Previously every values copy was on the entire column, wasting a lot of time!
    ' Could get this value by a cleverer, more dynamic method, but that depends on needs.
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 260

    ' Assign values, don't use copy/paste. Avoiding the clipboard speeds things up
    stockreturns.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value = index.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
    pricedata = prices.Range("A1",prices.Cells(lastrow,975))
    redim stockdata(1 to lastrow, 1 to 1952)    
    For col = 1 To 975
        'stockreturns.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Offset(0, 2 * col + 1).Value = prices.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Offset(0, col).Value
        for n = 1 to lastrow
        'offset so that +1
            stockdata(n,col*2+1+1)  = pricedata(n,col+1)
        next n
    next col
    'done with that

    'check value and change if need
    For col = 1 To 975

        For n = 2 To 260
            If stockdata(n + 1, 2 * col) = Null Or IsEmpty(stockdata(n + 1, 2 * col)) Then
                stockdata(n, 2 * col + 1) = Null
            Else
                stockdata(n, 2 * col + 1).Formula = stockdata(n, 2 * col) / stockdata(n + 1, 2 * col) - 1
                'stockdata(n, 2 * col + 1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End If
         Next n
    Next col
    stockreturns.Range("A1",stockreturns.Cells(lastrow,1952)) = stockdata
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = stockreturns.Range("B1:B" & lr)
    For col = 2 To 975
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range(stockreturns.Cells(1,2*col + 1),stockreturns.Cells(lr,2*col + 1),)
    next n
    rng.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    ' Reset Application settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Duc, I tested the code with 9 col loops as opposed to 975 and it works. How do I upload the workbook for you to take a look at?

Comment: How fun it's this one down voted. If you want to faster your code hundreds time faster than all solution above then somehow upload your code so I can help you with an optimized method which I studied from this article:http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2017/04/excel-vba-read-and-write-performance-test.html

Comment: It got downvoted before your edit since it wasn't an answer in the first place. How funny is it that you actually gave an answer after that happened. Let me give you an upvote since now you actually answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Main issue:**

This nested loop of yours executes 975 * 260 = 253.500 times:

```
For col = 1 To 975
    For n = 2 To 260
        prices.Range("A:A").Offset(0, col).Copy stockreturns.Range("A:A").Offset(0, 2 * col + 1)
        If stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value = Null Or IsEmpty(stockreturns.Cells(n + 1, 2 * col).Value) Then
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1) = Null
        Else
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).Formula = Cells(n, 2 * col) / Cells(n + 1, 2 * col) - 1
            stockreturns.Cells(n, 2 * col + 1).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End If
     Next n
Next col
```

**Summary of what you're doing, according to code in the question:**

Basically, what you're doing is get column B, C, D, etc. and copy them to D, E, G, etc. using the offset. Next you check in the stockreturns worksheet what the value of the copied cell in the next row is (e.g. you check D3, then D4 etc.) and based on that populate E2, E3, etc. with nulls, or, alternatively you take ((D2 / D3) - 1) as a value there. The initial check is to avoid division by zero errors, I assume.

**Note:** 
In those lines in your code you refer to `Cells(n, 2 * col)` so that would always be the `ActiveSheet`, whereas I assume you want to populate the worksheet `stockreturns` with those values. I.e. if you run the formula with worksheet `prices` activated, the formula's won't give the desired output.

**Working towards solution:**

For sure it would be way faster to not do 253.500 loops, but to populate everything at once for as far as possible. Since the column number varies everytime, we'll leave that loop in, but the nested 260 loops we can easily get rid of:

**Optimization to do 975 loops instead of 253.500:**

```
With stockreturns
    For col = 1 To 975
        prices.Range("A:A").Offset(0, col).Copy .Range("A:A").Offset(0, 2 * col + 1)
        'Now we fill up the entire 260 rows at once using a relative formula:
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[+1]C[-1]="""","""",(RC[-1]/R[+1]C[-1])-1)"
        'If you want a value instead of a formula, we replace the formula's with the value. If calculation is set to manual, you'll have to add an Application.Calculate here.
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).Value
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Next col
End With
```

This will already save major execution time. However, we can also save ourselves 975 calculate actions, by turning off calculations and only replacing the formulas with the values at the very end:

**Second optimization to avoid calculations during execution:**

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
With stockreturns
    For col = 1 To 975
        prices.Range("A:A").Offset(0, col).Copy .Range("A:A").Offset(0, 2 * col + 1)
        'Now we fill up the entire 260 rows at once using a relative formula:
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[+1]C[-1]="""","""",(RC[-1]/R[+1]C[-1])-1)"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * col + 1), .Cells(260, 2 * col + 1)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Next col
End With
Application.Calculate
stockreturns.UsedRange.value = stockreturns.UsedRange.value
```

This last version runs in seconds.
If it is acceptable for you to alter the `stockreturns` worksheet layout and use a continuous range to copy to at once, you won't need those 975 loops either but you can achieve the desired result with the following actions:

- Copy prices range
- Add the formula in another range
- Calculate
- Replace formulas with values
- Set numberformat

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rick, thanks so much for this detailed answer. I will have to try this code out to make sure it fits my data, but it looks much better than what I currently have. If someone could let me know how to upload the workbook here, I'd like to do that so you guys can get an idea of what I'm attempting to do with the code.

Comment: @Rik Sportel whoops I didn't notify you on the last one

Comment: @Rik, good breakdown of the task to speed things up. You should also avoid `.Copy` operations - see my answer.

Comment: @Wolfie, where can I upload it so that people can see what my end goal is?

Comment: Dropbox, Google Drive... wherever you like that you can link to. You'll be lucky to find someone who wants to invest time looking through your workbook though, I would think most of the speed improvements have been mentioned on this page already!

Comment: @Wolfie Depends. If he only needs the values, then value assignment is faster. If he needs the markup as well, then copying is faster.
The key is to access the Objects in the Worksheet(s) as little as possible, since VBA will do an IO operation for each nested object. 
I didn't write it in the Answer, but using `With` is also an optimization in that respect, since the worksheet itself will be in memory during that code block.

Comment: Yeah well if we were going really crazy about avoiding IO then we need to leverage arrays, but I don't think this process can be *that* slow! ;)